# Different Fingerprint on same machine in fingerprintjs2

Tags: javascript, fingerprintjs2

I am using Valve fingerprintjs2 for browser authentication.But it is giving me different id on same machine
it is not happened frequently but occurring this error in random case.For this i have also save the browser and other information but both the browser information are same but signature key is different.I am posting the information below please help me to resolve this issue.For this i am using

My JS Url:
http://server1.lmsin.com/machineauth/fingerprint2.js

**Detailed information**: 
user_agent = Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.
timezone_offset = -330
regular_plugins = Chrome PDF Plugin::Portable Document Format::application/x-google-chrome-pdf~pdf,Chrome PDF Viewer::
js_fonts = Arial,Arial Black,Arial Narrow,Arial Unicode MS,Book Antiqua,Bookman Old Style,Calibri,Cambria,Cambr

**Key**:658a83e0df743d4db554679e67b3ee25

**Detailed information**: 
user_agent = Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.
timezone_offset = -330
regular_plugins = Chrome PDF Plugin::Portable Document Format::application/x-google-chrome-pdf~pdf,Chrome PDF Viewer::
js_fonts = Arial,Arial Black,Arial Narrow,Arial Unicode MS,Book Antiqua,Bookman Old Style,Calibri,Cambria,Cambr

**Key**:4d2c79138aaae5b11c0fabd2b1a3d101

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. However it won't happen in all browser. In some browser it generates different fingerprint every time. Have you solved this issue?